# jQuery: Adding element after the 4th element for each set of 4 elements

Tags: jquery

Hi I am using bootstrap 4 grid and I am trying to insert with jquery a product zoom (retreiving with ajax) after the 4th element but depending where the user click for each set of 4 elements.

```
<div class="row" id="products">
 <div class="col-4">product 1</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 2</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 3</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 4</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 5</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 6</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 7</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 8</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 9</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 10</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 11</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 12</div>
</div>
```

> For exemple :

if user click on product 1, 2, 3 or 4 i would like to insert the zoom div **after product 4**

```
<div class="row" id="products">
 <div class="col-4">product 1</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 2</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 3</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 4</div>
 <div class="col-12">product zoom</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 5</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 6</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 7</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 8</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 9</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 10</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 11</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 12</div>
</div>
```

if user click on product 5, 6, 7 or 8 i would like to insert the zoom div **after product 8**

```
<div class="row" id="products">
 <div class="col-4">product 1</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 2</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 3</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 4</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 5</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 6</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 7</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 8</div>
 <div class="col-12">product zoom</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 9</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 10</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 11</div>
 <div class="col-4">product 12</div>
</div>
```

if user click on product 9, 10, 11 or 12 i would like to insert the zoom div **after product 12** and so on...

Any ideas how can i achieve this ?

I don't need help for ajax, no problem with that.
Thanks in advance everybody for any helps you can provide !

Comment: Post what you tried, perhaps we can assist with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should do it :

```
var cols = $('#products .col-4');
cols.click(function(){
    var el = $(this);
    // Get clicked element index
    var index = el.index();
    // Check in which "group" it belongs
    var group = Math.ceil(index / 4);
    // Insert what you want after the last item of that group
    $(cols.get((group * 4) - 1)).after('<div class="col-12">product zoom</div>');
});
```

Comment: This works.  Note that this would keep inserting the product zoom each time you clicked, so if you click 1 then 2, you'd have two zooms after the 4th element.  You can also use `after` to move an element.  So if only one should be present at a time, you could use `after` to move the zoom instead by passing it a reference to the `zoom` element.

Comment: This breaks after you've inserted a zoom, since the index for later elements will be offset and no longer match their product number.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using jQuery with the CSS selector :nth-child to insert after every 4th item:

`$('.col-4:nth-child(4n)').after('<div class="col-12">product zoom</div>');`

Reference https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/